# React-router redirect my routes in production mode

Tags: reactjs, tomcat, routes, react-router-v4, browser-history

I've got this route configuration in my React App:

```
index.js
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

and

```
App.js
      <Switch>
        <Route path={PathConst.toLoginPage} exact>
          {user ? <Redirect to={PathConst.toHomepage} /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={PathConst.toHomePage}>
          {user ? <Dashboard /> : <Redirect to={PathConst.toLoginPage} />}
        </Route>
        <AuthRoute path={PathConst.toUserPage} Component={UserPage} exact isAuthenticated={user} requiredRoles={[UserRoles.USER_VIEW]} />
      </Switch>
```

I'm using react-router-dom 4.3.1;

Let's say I want to open `/gui/users`

In localhost:3000 it works correctly both open page using  component and `window.open(${path})` or writing my path directly in the browser address bar (on another tab).
eg. `localhost:3000/gui/users`

In production mode it works correctly just with  component. While if I try to write my path in the browser (on another tab) or using `window.open(${path})` it automatically redirects me in my HomePage. eg. `production:8000/gui/users` redirects to `production:8000/gui/`

The backend is written with Spring, the web server is Tomcat.

I think it could be a problem with client-side routing. Any ideas how to solve it?